# CSS/HTML: Tooltip pushing content down

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I have a custom CSS Tooltip that when it appears, it pushes the other content down.  I know that I need to add `position: absolute` to get it working right, but I can't seem to figure out where...

**HTML:**

```
<p>Fluff</p>
<p>Fluff</p>
<p>Fluff</p>
<p>Fluff</p>
<p>Fluff</p>

    <div class="outer">

    <a class="tippy" href="">
        ICON<img src="" class="icon"/>
    </a>

    <div class="tooltip">
        STUFF<br/>
        STUFF<br/>
        STUFF<br/>
        STUFF<br/>
        STUFF<br/>
    </div>

    </div><!-- Container -->

<p>FluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluff</p>
<p>FluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluff</p>
<p>FluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluff</p>
<p>FluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluffFluff</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
.outer {
    width: 350px;
}

.tippy {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a.tippy:hover + div {
    display:block;
    float: right;
}

.tooltip {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 265px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    display: none;
}
.tooltip:after, .tooltip:before {
    border: solid transparent;
    content:' ';
    height: 0;
    right: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}
.tooltip:after {
    border-width: 11px;
    border-right-color: #ccc;
    top: 13px;
}
.tooltip:before {
    border-width: 14px;
    border-right-color: #333;
    top: 10px;
}
```

[**Fiddle:**](http://jsfiddle.net/49Js3/39/)

Comment: Impossible to tell from your code what is the tooltip and what is content without looking at the jsFiddle.

Comment: I'll change "demo" to "tooltip"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `position:relative` to `position:absolute` in the `.tooltip` CSS block.

You will also need to modify the CSS for positioning the tooltip due to this change.

If you modify `.outer` to have `position:relative` this is as simple as setting `.tooltip` as

```
left:55px;
top:-15px;
```

The resulting CSS (showing only the blocks that have changed):

```
.outer {
    width: 350px;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip {
    left: 55px;
    top: -15px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 265px;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    display: none;
}
```

And finally [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/49Js3/41/) showing it in action.

Comment: You are awesome.  I actually came close to this.  However, I used `margin: -43px 0 5px 50px;` instead of `left` and `top`.  Any reason why `left` and `top` would be better? I also didn't include `position: relative;` in the outer div and it still worked.  Any reason why?

Comment: Margin is based off the element's current position, so whether positioned absolute, relative or other it will still offset it by those values, and is a perfectly valid way to do what you want. It just makes more semantic sense to me to set up an absolutely positioned element with absolute values like `top` and `left` unless it needs otherwise. In the end it is up to you how you achieve the desired result now that you know two ways to do it.